# EF Core razor pages with Include, ThenInclude. Displaying string instead of Id

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, razor-pages

I have the models Client, Project, ClientComment, ProjectComment, ProjectStatus, RAGStatus, and Resource. I am displaying a table of client-related and project-related comments grouped by Client.

I need to add the related ProjectStatus, RAGStatus, and Resource to my table, but I have been unable to connect the additional entities in my Include/ThenInclude query.

The ProjectStatus, RAGStatus, and Resource are bound via ViewData/VieWBag in drop-down menus and therefore saving the respective Id (not the actual string) in the ClientComment, Project, and ProjectComment tables.

I have tried to create a ViewModel for the ProjectStatus, RAGStatus, and Resource, but I am unable to find the right combination of Include/ThenInclude to display all the information I need on my table.

The Client model:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClientComment> ClientComments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

The Project model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }
    public ProjectStatus ProjectStatus { get; set; }

    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectComment> ProjectComments { get; set; }
}
```

The ClientComment model:

```
public class ClientComment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public int RAGStatusId { get; set; }
    public RAGStatus RAGStatus { get; set; }

    public string StatusComment { get; set; }
    public string EscalationComment { get; set; }
    public string GeneralComment { get; set; }
    public double? EOQ { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public ClientComment ()
    {
        this.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
```

The ProjectComment model:

```
public class ProjectComment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public int RAGStatusId { get; set; }
    public RAGStatus RAGStatus { get; set; }

    public string StatusComment { get; set; }
    public string EscalationComment { get; set; }
    public string GeneralComment { get; set; }
    public double? EOQ { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public ProjectComment ()
    {
        this.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
```

The ProjectStatus model:

```
public class ProjectStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectStatusName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

The RAGStatus model:

```
public class RAGStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RAGStatusName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClientComment> ClientComments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectComment> ProjectComments { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

The Resource model:

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

The ClientVM model:

```
public class ClientVM
{
public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int ClientCommentId { get; set; }
    public string ClientStatusComment { get; set; }
    public int RAGStatusId { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectVM> Projectlist { get; set; }
    public List<RAGStatusVM> RAGStatuslist { get; set; }
}
```

The ProjectVM model:

```
public class ProjectVM
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectStatusComment { get; set; }
    public int RAGStatusId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
}
```

The PageModel:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<ClientVM> ClientVMList { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectVM> ProjectVMList { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceVM> ResourceVMList { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectStatusVM> ProjectstatusVMList { get; set; }
    public List<RAGStatusVM> RAGstatusVMList { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        var clientlist = await _context.Client
            .Include(c => c.ClientComments)
            .ThenInclude(cr => cr.RAGStatus)
            .Include(c => c.Projects)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.ProjectComments)
                .ThenInclude(pr => pr.RAGStatus).ToListAsync();

        ClientVMList = new List<ClientVM>();

        foreach (var item in clientlist)
        {
            ClientVM clientVM = new ClientVM()
            {
                Projectlist = new List<ProjectVM>()
            };
            clientVM.ClientId = item.Id;
            clientVM.ClientName = item.ClientName;
            if (item.ClientComments != null && item.ClientComments.Any())
            {
                clientVM.ClientStatusComment = item.ClientComments.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.LastUpdateDate).First().StatusComment;
            }
            else
            {
                clientVM.ClientStatusComment = "No StatusComment";
            }
            foreach (var projectItem in item.Projects)
            {

                ProjectVM projectVM = new ProjectVM
                {
                    ProjectId = projectItem.Id,
                    ProjectName = projectItem.ProjectName,
                    ProjectStatusId = projectItem.ProjectStatusId,
                    ResourceId = projectItem.ResourceId
                };
                if (projectItem.ProjectComments != null && projectItem.ProjectComments.Any())
                {
                    projectVM.ProjectStatusComment = projectItem.ProjectComments.OrderByDescending(pc => pc.LastUpdateDate).First().StatusComment;
                }
                else
                {
                    projectVM.ProjectStatusComment = "No StatusComment";
                }
                clientVM.Projectlist.Add(projectVM);
            }

            ClientVMList.Add(clientVM);
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

> Client1  | ClientStatusComment  | RAGStatus | ResourceName
>   Project1 | ProjectStatusComment | RAGStatus | ResourceName | ProjectStatusName
>   Project2 | ProjectStatusComment | RAGStatus | ResourceName | ProjectStatusName
>   
>   Client2  | ClientStatusComment  | RAGStatus | ResourceName
>   Project1 | ProjectStatusComment | RAGStatus | ResourceName | ProjectStatusName
>   Project2 | ProjectStatusComment | RAGStatus | ResourceName | ProjectStatusName

Comment: Do you can't get records in include.ThenInclude query ? I test that and it works on my side .

Comment: I receive the records I am expecting for the first two columns, but I cannot access the data from the RAGStatus, Resource and ProjectStatus tables. I can get the ProjectStatusId and the ResourceId as they are in the Project table, but I want to see the ProjectStatusName and the LongName (Resource) in my table. I cannot access the RAGStatus at all (not even the RAGStatusId.